# Getting the error "No active batch." when running any batch

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I am getting this error when running any batch on the site:

> No active batch.

I thought this may have been a server issue, so I tried it locally, but I got the same error. I tried deleting all the records in the batch table, but I also got the same result.

The only thing I can think of is that perhaps the web server is down. Why would that effect batches that do not connect to their servers?

Comment: Do you have the secure pages module installed?

Comment: ha, yeah I am @Clive, I just found the problem and posted the answer. thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Secure Pages](http://drupal.org/project/securepages) module, you have apply the patches provided for that module.

As I am using the Secure Pages module, that fixed my problem.

> #### Steps to install Secure Pages 7.x-dev
>
> - Set `$conf['https'] = TRUE;` in settings.php.
> - Apply these two patches:
>
>   - [#961508-21: Dual http/https session cookies interfere with drupal_valid_token()](http://drupal.org/node/961508#comment-5114188)
>   - [#471970-13: DrupalWebTestCase->getAbsoluteUrl should use internal browser's base URL](http://drupal.org/node/471970#comment-4196144)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It was caused by the secure pages issue. So I went to secure pages settings page, and in the ignore list, I added my url (e.g. admin/structure/abc). It worked good. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Update For Drupal 8, please, check this topic - https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3055287#comment-13911732

removing logger.factory service from the batch fix the problem